# Are there examples of Angular2 projects? Particularly complex routing (v2.0.0-rc.1)

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-routing

I am developing a web app using angular2 (2.0.0 rc 1) and am running into problems due to the lack of documentation, particularly when trying to create complex routing.

As 2.0.0 was only released a month or so ago there aren't many questions on SO or elsewhere to take inspiration from.

So in the absence of real documentation are there any project examples out there? Thanks

Comment: Angular2 isn't yet released. There are tons of related questions here under the `angular2` tag. Routing isn't fully ironed out yet and still changing. Angular.io contains routing docs though.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The docs on angular.io for routing describe the deprecated beta I believe. Cheers though

Comment: The RC is also deprecated. There are currently only deprecated routers. Currently the best bet is `@angular/router-deprecated` because it is more feature complete and more stable.

Comment: Take a look at [this blogpost](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/04/10/scalable-javascript-single-page-app-angular2-application-architecture/) and [source code](https://github.com/mgechev/scalable-architecture-demo).. Also [this](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app) if you're using `ngrx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Victor Savkin posted a blog article on this very subject just last night:

http://victorsavkin.com/post/145672529346/angular-router